# Pandas: Convert a row into a column and make all other entries the second column

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
            Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
control      x1    x2    x3    x4
obs1         o11   o12   o13   o14
obs2         o21   o22   o23   o24
...
obsn         on1   on2   on3   on4
```

I want to reshape it as follows (column headers are not needed):

```
     control Observation
1      x1        o11
2      x1        o12
3      x1        o13
...
m      xk        ok1
m+1    xk        ok2
...
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select your "control" row and use that to set your columns via `set_axis` from there its a simple `melt`.

The `sort_values` and `reset_index` aren't functionally necessary, but they align the `dataframe` with what your expected output is, so I've included them here:

```
control = df.loc["control", :]
observations = df.drop("control")

out = (observations.set_axis(control, axis=1)
       .melt(value_name="observation")
       .sort_values("observation")
       .reset_index(drop=True))

print(out)
  control observation
0      x1         o11
1      x2         o12
2      x3         o13
3      x4         o14
4      x1         o21
5      x2         o22
6      x3         o23
7      x4         o24
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a crude solution but it's not elegant. Say `df` is my data frame.

```
mdf = df.melt()
for col in df.columns:
    mdf.loc[mdf['variable'] == col, 'variable'] = df.loc['control', col]

mdf.drop(mdf[mdf['variable'] == mdf['value']].index, inplace=True)
```